# TFDS extract file name

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

In tfds, we do

```py
def _generate_examples(self, file_paths):
    for file_path in file_paths:
        yield file_path, {
            'image': image,
            'label': label
        }
```

I am already yielding file_path, how can I get it when i load the dataset? i.e

```py
data = tfds.load('dataset')
# print all file names
```

Comment: I think,  the tfds gives data in numpy array, not the raw file.

Comment: yes i want to know if it is possible? since we also yield it